# Run tests with Karate-Chrome (Connection refused exception)

Tags: docker, ui-automation, karate

Karate UI-based tests run successfully locally with karate-chrome (steps [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-chrome)) which starts a container with an exposed port.

Now, I am trying to run the tests **within** the karate-chrome container in CI. I have started the karate-chrome container with `KARATE_SOCAT_START=true`and then executed the java -jar (standalone jar) command to run the tests. Non-UI based tests pass but the UI tests are throwing the following exception:

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
15:26:09 DOCKER: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Note that driverTarget with docker has not been configured. Only the following driver's configuration:

```
  * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', start: false, showDriverLog: true, port:9222 ,pollAttempts: 5}
```

Is it possible to make it work this way or should a custom docker image be set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to run UI-based tests directly on `karate-chrome`. Therefore, I ended up creating a new docker image ([docker-openjdk8](https://hub.docker.com/r/uic004/docker-openjdk8)) to run the tests with driverTarget:

```
* configure driverTarget = { docker: 'ptrthomas/karate-chrome', showDriverLog: true}
```

This basically runs the tests with Docker-in-Docker (DIND) process. Would be happy to know if anybody else has got a better solution.

Comment: would be nice if you share the source of this container to help others

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but today I stumbled upon this very same issue where I had to configure Karate UI tests for automation. The solution I found was to configure the chrome driver as follows:

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true, port: 9222, pollAttempts: 5, addOptions:['--no-sandbox'], headless: true }
```

Then the karate standalone jar was able to launch the browser and all tests passed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your setup is not clear. But to use `configure driverTarget = { docker: 'ptrthomas/karate-chrome' }` means Docker should be installed on the machine where you are running the test.

I suggest you start looking at the [1.0 release](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide), and we have a reference test that uses the Docker container a little differently, without using `driverTarget`. You can find details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005331/143475

It would be great if after you get this working, you post your solution as another answer here so that it helps others and helps us improve the documentation if needed.

Comment: it looks like I do not need driverTarger as I am already running the tests inside the karate-chrome container. I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @UIC sorry I am not able to understand. so I'm giving up. hope someone else here can help you. docker is working for many others, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64457892/143475